# I need the proper Regex syntax to replace ,0<anything>, with ,"0<anything>", in VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am working within a VB.Net application and am trying to protect numbers with leading zeros (like zip codes for example) in a bunch of CSV files by declaring them a text using double quotes (") as text delimiters. 
The files are existing files, so I can't go back to the source and regenerate the files.

What would be the proper Regex syntax to find every occurrence of 
,0, 
and replace it with 
,"0

For example, make ,01234, into ,"01234", or ,0011112222, into ,"0011112222",

I know this should be 'brain dead' simple, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: What about `0`, which has no leading zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

```
(?<!\d)(0\d+)
```

Replace with...

```
"$1"
```

If you need to protect any single zeros then perhaps...

```
(?<!\d)(0\d{0,})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CFFpu8/1

Comment: Actually, I like this one better! Thank you all for your help in this. Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case you also want to avoid decorating numbers that are inside longer strings or are already enclosed by double quotes, you could try the following expression:

```
/(?<!")\b0\d+\b(?!")/g
```

In VB.net double quotes would probably have to be escaped:

```
Dim text As String = "01234, ""01234"", 0011112222, ""0011112222"", 100, 0, 11a00bc00123, 00foo."
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<!"")(\b0\d+\b)(?!"")", """$1""")
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

Output:

```
"01234", "01234", "0011112222", "0011112222", 100, 0, 11a00bc00123, 00foo.
```